# Nginx reverse proxy not working on domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, centos-web-panel

I have tried all the solution on SO but no success. I want to use Nginx as a "Node.js" app reverse proxy. With my current configurations, I was able to make it work when connecting to it through the server IP but not when using its domain name.My configuration details [pastebin.com/gMqpmDwj](http://pastebin.com/gMqpmDwj)

`http://Ipaddress:3000` works but `http://example.com` doesn't.

Here is the configuration of my Nginx proxy, stored in `/etc/Nginx/conf.d/domain.conf`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://ipaddress:3000;
    }
}
```

But when I try to access it works fine on `ip:port` but when on `domain:port` or without `port` it doesn't

Comment: Try setting `server_name` to your domain name. For example: `server_name example.com www.example.com`. On the other hand, is the server working on port 80 when you try to access using its IP?

Comment: I did try using server name as domain name but no success.
Yes it is working on port 80. I am using CWP and its showing default page onf both port 80 and domain name.

Comment: Its been more than 12 hours I am stuck on this issue.I tried all the combinations :(

Comment: And you are sure that you have configured your DNS server correctly? Can you check if your domain name is resolving to the proper IP?

Comment: Yes I am sure. It was working properly when I was using apache but not on nginx.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gMqpmDwj my configuration details.

Comment: Sorry, I have created a `minimum example` using NodeJS and NGINX and I can replicate the problem. Here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/guzmonne/nodejs_nginx. Try to run this on your machine, and see if it helps you figure out what is wrong with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue after following this link.I had multiple configuration files active that was causing problem.
[How to Configure Nginx Reverse Proxy for Nodejs on Centos](https://techrado.com/how-to-configure-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-on-centos/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user                nobody;
worker_processes    1;
pid                 /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 100;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.conf**

```
upstream nodejs_app {
    server <ipaddress>:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <domain_name>;

    location / {
        # websocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://nodejs_app/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "sendfile" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:29
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: I got an error like this.I just copy paste the same conf.

Comment: try one more time

Comment: nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "bytes" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/185.212.131.104.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: commend line 6 from your /etc/nginx/conf.d/185.212.131.104.conf